# Regex for escaping markup characters in java

Tags: java, regex, markup

I have saved messages with markup. it is using just a few markup functionalities for markup like bold, italic, strikethrough and code. What I need now is to strip those messages from any kind of markup, except for when in code. For example:

```
**bold**  _italic_ ~strike~ `**code**`
```

would return:

```
bold italic strike **code**
```

I currently use regex like this one for bold:

```
\*\*([^*]*)\*\*(?=(?:[^`\\]*(?:\\.|`(?:[^`\\]*\\.)*[^`\\]*`))*[^`]*$)
```

to strip my message from the formatting, but I am having a problem with composite markups, where multiple formatting is applied to the string like ***bold and italic*** at the same time.

```
**_bold and italic_**
```

Is there any way to strip that kind of message and something that would simplify the regex I am using?

Comment: Parsers are usually used for this sort of problem, not regex.

Comment: Look how complex your regex is.  Imagine coming back to this code in six months.  Or, imagine if another developer is assisting you and has to figure out what that regex is doing.  Do yourself a favor and just parse the content one character at a time.  It will look like more lines of code, but it will not actually be longer;  regex engines are heavyweight by necessity.

Comment: Stripe it as long as the result has not been modified. This way even of you have a really rare combination of format all of them will be striped, at any of the iterations, which will be just a few.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
replaceAll("`([^`]*)`|(\\*\\*|[_~])((?:(?!\\2).)*)\\2", "$1$3")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQzxJG/1/). *Details*:

- `` `([^`]*)` `` - backtick, then any zero or more non-backtick chars (captured into Group 1) and then a backtick
- `|` - or
- `(\*\*|[_~])` - Group 2: `**`, `_` or `~`
- `((?:(?!\\2).)*)` - Group 3: any char, zero or more occurrences but as many as possible that does not start with the char sequence captured into Group 2
- `\2` - Group 2 value.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/SCDHhW):

```java
String s = "**bold**  _italic_ ~strike~ `**code**`";
String regex = "(?s)`([^`]*)`|(\\*\\*|[_~])((?:(?!\\2).)*)\\2";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regex, "$1$3")); 
// => bold  italic strike **code**
```

For nested markers, replace all markdowns keeping substrings in backticks and as a post-processing step remove the backticks:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "**bold**  _italic_ ~strike~ `**code**` **_bold and italic_**";
        String rx = "(`[^`]*`)|(\\*\\*|[_~])((?:(?!\\2).)*)\\2";
        String prev = "";
        do {
            prev = s;
            s = s.replaceAll(rx, "$1$3");
        }
        while (!prev.equals(s));
        s = s.replaceAll("`([^`]*)`", "$1");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/QGDVi2). Output:

```
bold  italic strike **code** bold and italic
```

Comment: This is not working for the case where I mentioned I have a problem , ant that is combined formatting:
**_bold and italic_**

Comment: @Marko You can go on trying to solve it yourself, or update the question with a couple of test cases showing the real problem that you are using.

Comment: thanks for simplifying the regex, but that test case which I mention is already in the question.

Comment: @Marko You should have specified the expected behavior for that input.